# Expandable Recyclerview Android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, expandablerecyclerview

I tried to create recyclerview with its adapter, working fine but failed to create 
child recyclerview on click of its parent Item.
Required this type of layout https://github.com/thoughtbot/expandable-recycler-view
but unfortunately failed to resolve AS dependency as it is too old.

I also tried to take recyclerview in parent adapter but its not working with wrap_content i have to specify length of Recycler which is not possible in my case i have to draw dynamic layout.

Comment: Could you please post your code, it would be more helpful.

Comment: Hi @Erum recycler view does not have expanding feature , we have to implement by our self there are two ways 1) You can have a recycler view at row item and set adaper in onBindViewHolder() 2) you have to change view by providing  different layout in oncreateView() based upon type